# amazon athena and confluent schema registry

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, avro, amazon-athena, confluent-schema-registry

We are planning to offload events from Kafka to S3 (e.g via using kafka connect). The target is to spin up a service (e.g. like amazon Athena) and provide a query interface on top of the exported avro events. The obstacle is that amazon Athena avro SerDe (uses org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe) does not support the magic bytes that schema registry is utilising for storing the schema id. Do you know of any alternative that can play nice with confluent schema registry?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using S3 Connect's AvroConverter does not put any schema ID in the file. In fact, after the message is written, you lose the schema ID entirely.

We have lots of Hive tables that are working fine with these files, and users are querying using Athena, Presto. SparkSQL, etc.

Note: If you wanted to use AWS Glue, S3 Connect doesn't (currently, as of 5.x) offer automatic Hive partition creation like the HDFS Connector, so you might want to look for alternatives if you wanted to use it that way.